# How to know which button is clicked?

Tags: android

There are two buttons in each item of ListView.I want to control the Activity control. I should operate it in Activity, and can not set the listener to button directly.

So I set this code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
int position, long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});
```

How to know which button of item is clicked?

Comment: it is the view in View view so you can do view.getId() and check if it is equal to R.id.button1 or R.id.button2

Comment: Probably you should consider setting onItemClickListener to each button inside your adapter, can you attach getView() method from your adapter?

Answer (score 0):

just set different ids for these buttons in xml-layout

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
int position, long id) {
    switch (view.getId) {
    case R.id.btn1: ...
    case R.id.btn2: ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle it in adapter class.It will be most suitable way So make your custom adapter and then try this way in your getView method:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) 
    {
       if(convertView == null)
       {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView  = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, null);
       }

       Button Button1= (Button)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.BUTTON1_ID);
       Button Button2= (Button)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.BUTTON2_ID);

       Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
       { 
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
               // Your code that you want to execute on this button click
           }

       });
     Button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
       { 
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
               // Your code that you want to execute on this button click
           }

   });


   return convertView ;
}
```

Comment: @mayuhu Notify me whehther this helps you or not?